# Yii - Error 404 on /rights/authItem

Tags: php, yii

I have a problem with the Yii urlManager.
I try to access /rights/authItem/ (I have the "Rights" module installed) but it gives me `404 error "Unable to resolve the request "rights/authItem"`.
Until now it worked all of the time.

Here my urlManager setup:

```
'urlManager'=>array(
            'urlFormat'=>'path',
            'showScriptName'=>false,
            'caseSensitive'=>false,
            'rules'=>array(
                '<controller:\w+>/<id:\d+>'=>'<controller>/view',
                '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',
                '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',
                'app/<idcliente>'=>'app',
                'app/<idcliente>/<controller:\w+>'=>'app/<controller>',
                'app/<idcliente>/<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/id/<id:\d+>'=>'app/<controller>/<action>',
                'app/<idcliente>/<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>'=>'app/<controller>/<action>',

                ),
            ),
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use

> 'urlManager' => array(
>
> ```
>         'urlFormat' => 'path',
>         'rules' => array(
>             '<controller:\w+>/<id:\d+>' => '<controller>/view',
>             '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>' => '<controller>/<action>',
>             '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>' => '<controller>/<action>',
>         ),
>
>     ),
> ```

Answer (score 1):

Check if you have the rights modules registered at your config/main.php.

Before install:

```
'modules'=>array( 
 'rights'=>array( 
 'install'=>true, // Enables the installer. 
 ), 
),
```

After install:

```
'modules'=>array( 
 'rights'=>array( 
 'install'=>false,
 ), 
),
```

You can check de complete documentation at: http://yii-rights.googlecode.com/files/yii-rights-doc-1.2.0.pdf